# convert windows path to unix path inside wine application command line

Tags: shell, windows, filenames, wine

I'm running a windows application in wine, which executes configurable commands to run external applications (e.g. an diff editor to show differences between two source files). So these commands are executed by the windows application executed by wine.

Currently I'm using the following command to execute a native Linux application (in this case the geany editor) from the wine application:

```
wineconsole cmd /c start /unix /usr/bin/geany %file
```

Geany is starting, but the file path inside the windows variable `%file` contains a windows path with the drive letter, like `Z:\home\user\...`, so geany fails to open the file.

I know that `winepath -u <path>` could be used to convert any windows path into an equivalent UNIX path (and vise versa).

Is it possible to use this `winepath` inside the `wineconsole` command as substitution of the batch variable `%file`?

For example I thought about something like this:

```
wineconsole cmd /c start /unix /usr/bin/geany $(winepath -u %file)
```

Obviously this is not working.

Thank you!