# How can I make / \ replacement more efficient in console?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, console

In a Windows/Linux environment, I'm having trouble with copying and pasting file system links to AND from!
Right now, I use Gitbash (uses / for folder/subf ) which has been helpful. BUt it wants directories like this:

```
/c/Users/me/Documents/clamchowdah.txt (Non-windows) 
=
C:\Users\me\Documents\clamchowdah.txt (Windows)
```

Is my only option to use awk or sed or is there some facility I can use?

Comment: It is not clear where you have this pathname, and whether you want to convert it to the Windows style or to the Unix style.

Comment: Might be answered in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413376/convert-file-path-from-linux-to-windows-format-for-wine-tool winepath might get you there

Comment: Thanks. I'll add detail to the question and try the link

Comment: On every Microsoft operating system since MS-DOS, both the `/` and ```\``` characters were supported as path separators.  If you are not able to use forward slashes on Windows, it's due to a problem in the application; it's applying some invalid check or other processing and not just passing the path down to the OS.